# Error al ejecutar un contenedor con docker compose con variables

Tags: docker

He creado un docker compose, usando las imagenes del hub de docker con el siguiente codigo

```
    version: "3"

services:
   database:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_dades:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${PASSWORD}"
       MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
       MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}"
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${PASSWORD}"
     container_name: "${CONTAINER_NAME_DB}"  

   wordpress:
     image: wordpress:5.7
     expose:
       - 80
     restart: always
     environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: "${DOMINI}"
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "${CONTAINER_WP_PORT}"
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${PASSWORD}"
     container_name: "${CONTAINER_NAME_WP}"
volumes:
    db_dades:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Y tengo las siguientes variables de entorno

```
CONTAINER_NAME=luis
CONTAINER_NAME_WP=luiswp
CONTAINER_NAME_DB=luisdb
CONTAINER_WP_PORT=luisdb:3306
PASSWORD=secreto
DOMINI=luis.com
MYSQL_DATABASE=pepe
MYSQL_USER=pepe
```

Me da error de conexión a la base de datos. He hecho varias pruebas cambiando las variables y no consigo arrancarlo

Que hago mal?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Los archivos `docker-compose.yml` y `.env` están ubicados en el mismo directorio? Además te faltan algunas comillas, por ejemplo en `MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}"`

Comment: Si, estan en el mismo directorio. Ya he añadido las comillas pero me sigue dando error de conexion. Estoy como loco (gracias porloscerros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas de pasar variables de ambientes a un archivo `docker-compose.yml`. Esta forma funciona:

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= ${PASSWORD}
  - MYSQL_DATABASE= {MYSQL_DATABASE}
  - MYSQL_USER= ${MYSQL_USER}
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD= ${PASSWORD}
```

Y recuerda que yaml es muy estricto con el espaciado.